# Why does hirb.yml ignore User?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-console, hirb

I have a `config/hirb.yml` which looks a bit like this

```
:output:
  BlogEntry:
    :options:
      :fields:
        - id
        - title
        - url
  User:
    :options:
      :fields:
        - id
        - first_name
        - last_name
```

In the rails console, Hirb will properly format `BlogEntry.all` according to the hirb.yml specification, but will not do that for `User.all`.

Why? And how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here:

https://github.com/cldwalker/hirb/issues/40

Thanks to @cldwalker for answering the exact same question there. (I've modified the below quote so it syncs to my question.)

> You're doing `User.all` but you're not getting back user objects. *You're
>   getting back objects which are some subclass of user.* Your configuration only supported
>   User objects. To have `User.all` and its subclasses receive the
>   configuration, add the `:ancestor: true` property:
>
> ```
> :output:
>   User:
>     :ancestor: true
>     :options:
>       :fields:
>        - id
>        - first_name
>        - last_name
> ```

The documentation that I didn't find at first, which is handy for knowing how to use `hirb.yml`: http://tagaholic.me/hirb/doc/classes/Hirb/Formatter.html